# Unable to edit mongoose document

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using mongoose library for mongodb.
I am trying to save last login time with below code as suggested [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html).

```
UserModel.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function (err, doc) {
        //console.log('doc', doc);
        doc.lastLoginTime = new Date();
        doc.save();
    });
```

I am unable to edit doc it stays the same. What am i missing here?
My schema is

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.String,
        required: true,
        //unique: true,
        set: toLower
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
}, { strict: false });
```

Comment: Is there a `lastLoginTime` property defined in the schema? If not then add it there.

Comment: I have used { strict: false } in schema. update is not working even if i modify existing property.

Comment: @AnkurAkvaliya could you share your schema?

Comment: @TalhaAwan, i have edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the following in the documentation on [`strict`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict):

> *NOTE: Any key/val set on the instance that does not exist in your schema is always ignored, regardless of schema option.*

You need to use [`doc.set()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-set):

```
doc.set('lastLoginTime', new Date());
```